# Coderush xpress (11.2.11) not working in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush-xpress

I've just upgraded CodeRush Xpress from 10.1.4 to 11.2.11 (the latest version).

Although the DexExpress menu has been restored, and I can still get to the options screen (CTRL + Shift + Alt + O), but none of the other shortcuts (e.g. CTRL + ') do anything. In the options screens, the the Refactor short is set and is enabled.

There also used to be a 'Refactor!' context menu that no longer appears.

I've enabled the message log, but it doesn't flinch when I try any key combo - it's doing absolutely nothing.

I've also tried repairing the installation but no joy... and have disabled all other VS extensions.

Am I missing something? Has anyone got this working with VS2010 (v10.0.040219.1 SP1Rel)?

I've also tried posting on the DX forums but they are out of action at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My contact with DevExpress is detailed in [this thread](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q400881).

I now have it working on my main PC, and working substantially on my second PC. It's not 100% certain what the cause was - but certainly the installer I downloaded from the main site did not work, whereas a [different installer](http://downloads.devexpress.com/Share/IDE/CRX/CodeRushXpress-11.2.11.exe) that they provided did work. [I'm not sure how long this installer will remain]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the DevExpress Support Team is better equipped to resolve such issues. DX forums are now available but they are read-only. Use the new [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/) instead. In addition, support [@] devexpress.com is a fast way to get help from the official DevExpress support.

Comment: The 'Ask a Question' pages were down when I posted, but then came back up again. I got as far as typing in my question, but it went back down before I could submit it. "Temporary Unavailable [sic]". I think they are upgrading their site/back-end applications today... looks like I'll just have to be patient.